# Comma separated with/without spaces change behaviour. Spaces are skipped though

Tags: antlr4

First of all, thanks a lot for your time.

Practicing a little bit more with antlr4, I made this grammar (below).

**Input**

The tested input is the following:

`text to search query_on:fielda,fieldab fielda:"123" sort_by:+fielda,-fieldabc`

This produces the next output starting to fail on the query_on-varname rule.

```
(start (query (expr (text_query text to search) (query_on query_on : (varname fielda,fieldab fielda)))) : "123" sort_by : + fielda, - fieldabc\n)
```

If instead of this input I separate the commas with spaces:

`text to search query_on:fielda , fieldab fielda:"123" sort_by:+fielda , -fieldabc`

The output is much more similar to "my" expexted output:

```
(start (query (expr (text_query text to search) (query_on query_on : (varname fielda) , (varname fieldab)) (filters (binary_op (varname fielda) : (value "123"))) (sorting_fields sort_by : (sorting_field (sorting_order (asc +)) (varname fielda)) , (sorting_field (sorting_order (desc -)) (varname fieldabc\n))))) <EOF>)
```

The only failing part is the last `\n`.

**Expected**

The expected results is the same as before but accepting the varname `fieldabc` and skipping the `\n`.

```
(start (query (expr (text_query text to search) (query_on query_on : (varname fielda) , (varname fieldab)) (filters (binary_op (varname fielda) : (value "123"))) (sorting_fields sort_by : (sorting_field (sorting_order (asc +)) (varname fielda)) , (sorting_field (sorting_order (desc -)) (varname fieldabc))))))
```

**Questions**

Therefore:

1. Why the grammar is sensitive to the spaces around a comma ?
2. Similarly, why the `\n` char is not skipped at the end ?

Thanks!

**GRAMMAR**

```
grammar SearchEngine;

// Grammar
start: query EOF;

query
    : '(' query+ ')'
    | query (OR query)+
    | expr
    ;

expr: text_query query_on? filters* sorting_fields?;

text_query: STRING+;

query_on: QUERY_ON ':' varname (',' varname)*;

filters: binary_op+;

binary_op: varname ':' value;

sorting_fields: SORT_BY ':' sorting_field (',' sorting_field)*;

sorting_field: sorting_order varname;

sorting_order: (asc|desc);
asc: '+';
desc: '-';


varname
    : FIELDA
    | FIELDAB
    | FIELDABC
    ;

value: STRING;

// Lexer rules (tokens)
WHITE_SPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;

OR: O R;
QUERY_ON: Q U E R Y '_' O N;
SORT_BY: S O R T '_' B Y;

FIELDA: F I E L D A;
FIELDAB: F I E L D A B;
FIELDABC: F I E L D A B C;

STRING: ~[ :()+-]+;

// Fragments (not tokens)
fragment A: [aA];
fragment B: [bB];
fragment C: [cC];
fragment D: [dD];
fragment E: [eE];
fragment F: [fF];
fragment G: [gG];
fragment H: [hH];
fragment I: [iI];
fragment J: [jJ];
fragment K: [kK];
fragment L: [lL];
fragment M: [mM];
fragment N: [nN];
fragment O: [oO];
fragment P: [pP];
fragment Q: [qQ];
fragment R: [rR];
fragment S: [sS];
fragment T: [tT];
fragment U: [uU];
fragment V: [vV];
fragment W: [wW];
fragment X: [xX];
fragment Y: [yY];
fragment Z: [zZ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `STRING` Lexer rule accepts tabs and linefeeds.  Try:

```
STRING: ~[ :()+-,\t\r\n]+;
```

(Having your `WHITESPACE` rule above it won't affect this, because ANTLRs Lexer rules will select the longest sequence of characters that match any Lexer rule).  This is also, why you'll usually see grammars require some sort of delimiter on strings.  (The delimiters also distinguish between identifiers and string literals in most languages)

Comment: Oks, thanks for your answer!, this solves the last `\n`. But what about the commas ?, why is it wrongly consuming the comma after a defined token ?

Comment: I missed the part about the comma.  I've amended the answer to exclude commas from strings as well.  I suspect you'll find that this unusual definition of a string (no delimiters (" or '), will be the source of continued pain.

Comment: But the problem is not related with the STRING definition (afaik). It is related with the tokenization. The wrong behavior happens when parsing the varnames, not the values.

Comment: Your `STRING` rule is a tokenization rule.  Try dumping/inspecting your token stream.  I believe you'll find quite a number of unexpected `STRING` tokens.